# How to set the CurrentPage property of a TabbedPage in the OnCurrentPageChanged method?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

```
protected override void OnCurrentPageChanged()
    {
        base.OnCurrentPageChanged();

            if (CurrentPage == firstPage)
            {
                CurrentPage = secondPage;
            }
        }
    }
```

When I set the CurrentPage property of a TabbedPage in the OnCurrentPageChanged() method, something goes wrong:

1. If I switch to a page that matches a condition using swipe, the app hangs.
2. If I click on a page in the tab bar, the page does not change to the desired page (as I understand it, in this case, the assignment is performed before the page is reassigned).

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  Changing the basic navigation behavior is likely to lead to a VERY poor experience for the user.

Comment: @Jason The page displays the schedule. Tabs are Monday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday. I want to make a back button to the left of Monday, similarly at the end of the week. This will allow navigation between weeks.

Comment: @Jason or is there a way to somehow customize the Tabbar to place buttons on it?

Comment: ok, that's interesting.  But isn't each page really the same, just with a different days data driving it?  So you really just need to tell the pages to change their data?

Comment: @Jason yes i need to change data on pages

Comment: If write `OnCurrentPageChanged` in TabPage ,it will work. you can show total code about where page `OnCurrentPageChanged` in.

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
    myTabs.CurrentPageChanged += Handle_CurrentPageChanged;

    void Handle_CurrentPageChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // you will either want to add a try/catch here, or test that 
        // Children.Count > 1 (or whatever your number of pages is) to
        // prevent this from blowing up as the tabs are initializing
            if (CurrentPage == Children[0])
            {
                CurrentPage = Children[1];
            }
    }
```

Comment: I tested it in a sample app and it worked fine.  What specifically is not working?  Is the event firing?  Are there errors or exceptions?

Comment: At the first attempt simply does not work, at the second leaves in never-ending loop without exceptions